# How to remove setSelectionIndicatorImage when presenting the UIViewcontroler on UITabBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am using `TabBarViewController` and presenting the `UIViewControllers` on `UITabBar`. while presenting the `TabBar` first time i need  `setSelectionIndicatorImage`, in that presenting other view controller on same `TabBar` at that i Don't want  `setSelectionIndicatorImage`. How can i achieve this?